# Creating new instance of Pusher form javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I wanted to know when you do `new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}")` from the JS does it create a new object or hooks on to already available object identified by the `PUSHER_KEY`. The problem I am facing is I am not able to access pusher defined as

```
var pusher = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}");
var commonChannel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
    commonChannel.bind('test-event', function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

in a A.js from B.js.
When I try doing something like this from B.js

```
var commonChannel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
    commonChannel.bind('test-event', function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

I get `ReferenceError: pusher is not defined` but when I redefine pusher from B.js as

```
var pusherLocal = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}")
var channel = pusherLocal.subscribe('test-channel');
channel.bind('test-event', function(data) {
  alert(data.text);
});
```

I get `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error. Can anyone please give me some pointer what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in your page

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('key', {
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('refresh-channel');
    channel.bind('refresh-event', function(data) {
      alert();
    });
</script>
```